# Adding bibliography in pylatex

Tags: bibliographies, python, pylatex

I am interested in using PyLatex to automatize a table with several entries in such a way that I don't need to go through it manually every time that I need to change or add an entry. In the last column of this table, the reference from where I took the entry is needed.

So far, I haven't found any example of how to use PyLatex with Bibliography stiles, may you know an example of how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing special needed really, just a matter of adding the appropriate package etc. to the preamble, and `\printbibliography` (or `\bibliography{<filename>}`) in the document. The code is short and, I suppose, fairly self-explanatory.

```
import pylatex as pl

# dict with data for table - dict key is citation key
tabledata = dict(
                 aksin=['Foo', 42],
                 angenendt=['Bar', 7],
                 bertram=['Baz',3.14],
                 doody=['Foobar',199]
                 )

doc = pl.Document()

# add biblatex package to preamble
doc.preamble.append(pl.Package('biblatex',options=['sorting=none']))
doc.preamble.append(pl.Command('addbibresource',arguments=["biblatex-examples.bib"]))

# make table
with doc.create(pl.Tabular("l l l",booktabs=True)) as table:
    table.add_row(['Desc','Number','Cite'])
    table.add_hline()
    for key in tabledata.keys():
        table.add_row(tabledata[key]+[pl.Command('cite',arguments=[key])])


doc.append(pl.Command('printbibliography'))

doc.generate_tex('ex')
```

That Python script will generate this code in `ex.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
%
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}%
\addbibresource{biblatex{-}examples.bib}%
%
\begin{document}%
\normalsize%
\begin{tabular}{@{}l l l@{}}%
\toprule%
Desc&Number&Cite\\%
\midrule%
Baz&3.14&\cite{bertram}\\%
Foobar&199&\cite{doody}\\%
Foo&42&\cite{aksin}\\%
Bar&7&\cite{angenendt}\\\bottomrule%
%
\end{tabular}%
\printbibliography%
\end{document}
```

Disregarding the sillyness of starting with `\normalsize` and ending *every* line with a `%`, the one problem that needs to be fixed is to remove the braces around the `-` in `\addbibresource`. That is, it should be `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}`. (I don't know why those braces are added, nor how to remove them.)

Running the usual `pdflatex` + `biber` + `pdflatex` on `ex.tex`, and you get

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue. Just take the code from Torborn T. and for erasing the brackets "{" and "}". Type this command:

```
doc.preamble.append(pl.Command('addbibresource',arguments=[pl.NoEscape(r"biblatex-examples.bib")]))
```

instead of:

```
doc.preamble.append(pl.Command('addbibresource',arguments=["biblatex-examples.bib"]))
```